# Is there any compiler to generate slides from unzipped ppt file for iOS objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, powerpoint

i am working on ppt reader ios. i unzipped the ppt file and able to analyze the structure . All the info are in .xml files. is there any compiler or view available to generate slides out of it . ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i wont stop hunting.